# Convolution filter on android not working as intended

Tags: java, android, image, editing, convolution

I'm having trouble to get my convolution filter for Android to work properly. The result image is far from what it should look like after applying certain masks. Regardless of chosen filter, the result image contains a lot of noises and doesn't look as it should. Here's my Convolution Filter class:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class ConvolutionFilter {

    public Bitmap apply_Mask(int[] mask, Bitmap image) {
        int c;
        Bitmap preview;
        preview=image;

         int r=0;
         int g=0;
         int b=0;

         int weight=0;
         int weightSum=0;
         int counter=0;

         for (int i = 0; i < mask.length; i++)
         {
             weightSum += (int)mask[i];
         }

         for (int i = 0; i < (image.getWidth()-1); i++)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < (image.getHeight()-1); j++)
             {
                 r = g = b = 0;
                 counter = 0;

                  for (int o = i - 1; o <= i + 1; o++)
                 {
                     for (int p = j - 1; p <= j + 1; p++)
                     {
                         if ((o == -1 && (p == -1 || p == image.getHeight())) || (o == image.getWidth() && (p == -1 || p == image.getHeight())))
                             c = image.getPixel(i, j);
                         else if (o == -1 || o == image.getWidth())
                             c = image.getPixel(i, p);
                         else if (p == -1 || p == image.getHeight())
                             c = image.getPixel(o, j);
                         else
                             c = image.getPixel(o, p);

                         weight = (int)mask[counter];

                         r += ( Color.red(c)* weight);
                         b += (Color.blue(c) * weight);
                         g += (Color.green(c) * weight);

                         counter++;
                     }
                 }
                 if (weightSum == 0)
                     weightSum = 1;
                 r = r / weightSum;
                 b = b / weightSum;
                 g = g / weightSum;

                 if (r < 0)
                     r = 0;
                 if (r > 255)
                     r = 255;

                 if (b < 0)
                     b = 0;
                 if (b > 255)
                     b = 255;

                 if (g < 0)
                     g = 0;
                 if (g > 255)
                     g = 255;



                 preview.setPixel(i, j, Color.rgb(r, g, b));


             }

         }
         return preview;
    }
}
```

Here's how I use it:

```
laplacian.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=getIntent();
            final Uri uri=intent.getParcelableExtra("imageUri");



            int[] laplacian = { 
                    0, -1, 0, 
                    -1, 4, -1, 
                    0, -1, 0 };
            String str=new String("Trwa przetwarzanie...");
            Toast.makeText(FiltersMenu.this, str , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent1=new Intent(FiltersMenu.this,DisplayingProcessedImage.class);
            intent1.putExtra("filtr", laplacian);
            intent1.putExtra("imageUri", uri);
            startActivity(intent1);

        }
    });
```

And finally here I display the edited image, but the outcome is different from what I expect:

```
public class DisplayingProcessedImage extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_displaying_processed_image);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    Uri uri=intent.getParcelableExtra("imageUri");
    int[] filtr=intent.getIntArrayExtra("filtr");
    String str=uri.toString();
    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(str);

    Bitmap bitmap2 = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true);






    ConvolutionFilter filter=new ConvolutionFilter();

    ImageView imgView;
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(filter.apply_Mask(filtr, bitmap2));

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.displaying_processed_image, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? I keep getting the "Skipped xxx frames! The application might be doing too much work on its main thread" message. Does it mean it skips certain calculations on pixels?

**Problem solved**: As someone pointed out on different forum I was making calculations on an already modified bitmap:

```
preview=image;
```

Adding:

```
Bitmap preview=Bitmap.createBitmap(image);
```

fixed the issue.